# Get values from 2nd occurrence

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have one question in SQL Server.

How to get values from 2nd occurrence from the `_` symbol in SQL Server.

Table:Product_details

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[product_details](
    [name] [varchar](500) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[product_details] ([name]) VALUES (N'abc_xyz_pen')
INSERT [dbo].[product_details] ([name]) VALUES (N'def_rav_pen_two')
INSERT [dbo].[product_details] ([name]) VALUES (N'ade_rav_ted_ted_pen')
INSERT [dbo].[product_details] ([name]) VALUES (N'te_ty_te_de_rd_te')
```

Based on above table I want output like below

| Name |
| --- |
| pen |
| pen_two |
| ted_ted_pen |
| te_de_rd_te |

I tried like below

```
select substring(name,charindex('_',name,1),len(name))
from product_details
```

Above query not giving exact result.

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```sql
SELECT
    name,
    SUBSTRING(name, CHARINDEX('_', name, CHARINDEX('_', name) + 1) + 1, LEN(name)) AS second
FROM [dbo].[product_details];
```

For an explanation, the above takes a substring of the name starting one position past the *second* underscore.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of `CHARINDEX`'s and `STUFF` works well here:

```sql
SELECT STUFF(pd.[name],1,CI2.I,'')
FROM dbo.product_details pd
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('_',pd.[name])))CI1(I)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('_',pd.[name],CI1.I+1)))CI2(I);
```